# ES6 Pass paremeter to function which called from callback function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, pixi.js

I am trying to pass a parameter to a function which is called in the callback function, is that possible with es6 or javascript? here is the example below :

```
   sprite.on('mousedown', this.onDragStart)
         .on('touchstart', this.onDragStart)
         .on('mouseup', this.onDragEnd)
         .on('mouseupoutside', this.onDragEnd)
         .on('touchend', this.onDragEnd)
         .on('touchendoutside', this.onDragEnd)
         .on('mousemove', this.onDragMove);
         .on('touchmove', this.onDragMove);



   onDragStart(event) {
           this.data = event.data;
           this.alpha = 0.5;
           this.dragging = true;
           this.selected  = true;
       }

    onDragMove(arg) {

        if (this.dragging) {
            var newPosition = this.data.getLocalPosition(this.parent);
            arg.m_orange.setPosition(newPosition.x, newPosition.y);
        }
    }

    onDragEnd() {
        this.alpha = 1;
        this.dragging = false;
        this.data = null;
        this.selected = false;
    }
```

I want to pass a parameter to function onDragMove, which is called only when the mouse moving, is this possible?

if no, there is any other way to pass a keyword this of the parent class to onDragMove function?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it using es6 arrow-func instead of bind.

```
on('mousemove', (ev) => this.onDragMove(ev, otherArg))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for that:

```
on('mousemove', this.onDragMove.bind(thisArg, otherArg))
```